# QThread : how to stop an infinite loop 

Tags: c, qt, qthread

I execute in a Qthread an image processing procedure taking around 3 hours without the possibility to put some check points inside it for a exit gate. The problem is I cannot stop it. This code represents this problem :

```
class Toto : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
    void exec(){      
        //I represent the real process  with an infinite loop
        while(1==1);
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication aa(argc, argv);
    QThread * t1 = new QThread;
    Toto * toto1 = new Toto;
    QThread * t2 = new QThread;
    Toto * toto2 = new Toto;
    QPushButton push;
    push.show();
    toto1->moveToThread(t1);
    toto2->moveToThread(t2);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(toto1, "exec", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(toto2, "exec", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QApplication::connect(&push, SIGNAL(pressed()), t1,SLOT(terminate()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QApplication::connect(&push, SIGNAL(pressed ()), t2,SLOT(terminate()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    t2->start();
    t1->start();
    return aa.exec();
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Philosophically speaking; something would not be an infinite loop if one is able to stop it.

Comment: Infinite in the thread referential !!! ;)

Comment: I've built your example code and it works, the thread gets terminated.  Windows 7, Qt 4.7.4

Comment: Yes, I also made this try on windows and that's work. It is only OB linux where the problem occurs. Thanks geotovros !!! My application will run on windows. So everything is half all right.

Answer (score 0):

The thread will never process the terminate() signal because the exec slot never returns control to the thread's event loop.

Instead you should make a slot in an object running in the QApplication's mainloop. Connect the button to that slot, and then call terminate() on the appropriate thread object.

Comment: Actually, calling terminate() is bad practice. Instead, your infinite loop should have some flag that it checks periodically and if that flag is set, you break out of the loop. You, of course, change the flag inside another function in the thread. You may want to also look at QtConcurrent for solving these sort of long running tasks.

Comment: Yes but if my slot is in the QApplication's mainloop, I lost the concurrency tasks :/

Comment: Thanks  Trenton SchulzHowever, However my infinite loop represents more than two hundreds algorithms of my image processing library. I cannot add a break point for each one. In other multi-threading library, we can kill a thread as a "pirate" without a flag.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you need to first call the `void setTerminationEnabled ( bool enabled = true )` method and enable termination. Otherwise termination will be deferred.

Comment: True, according to the documentation, "thread can be terminated at any point in its code path." But when you try it, nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: So you've tried to enable termination and nothing helped? Did you try to call `t1->terminate();` from your main thread? E.g. `QApplication::connect(&push, SIGNAL(pressed()), this,SLOT(terminateAllThreads())); void terminateAllThreads() { t1->terminate(); }`

Comment: I try almost every possibilities even this one.